# Duplicate child entries when saving an entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I am getting duplicates of child when updating entity.

Submission Code:

```
Report report = _ReportService.GetReport(id);

report.AddDocument(
    new Document
    {
        Extension = qqfile.Substring(qqfile.Length - 3),
        Path = g.ToString(),
        Type = TypeHelper.GetDocumentType(report.Status),
        User = MemberFactory.MemberInfo
    }
);


report.Status = (ReportStatus)((int)report.Status + 1);

_reportRepository.SaveOrUpdate(report);



public class Document : BaseModel
{
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual string Extension { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentMap : ClassMap<Document>
{
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Id(x=> x.Id);
        Map(x=> x.Extension);
        Map(x => x.Path);
        Map(x => x.CreateDate);
        Map(x => x.LastModified);
        Map(x => x.Type).CustomType<int>();

        References<User>(x => x.User);
        References<Report>(x => x.Report);
    }
}

public class Report : BaseModel
{
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AppointmentStart { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AppointmentEnd { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual long Kareo_Id { get; set; }

    public Report() 
    {
        this.Status = ReportStatus.New;
        this.Documents = new List<Document>();
    }

    public virtual void AddDocument(Document document)
    {
        document.Report = this;
        this.Documents.Add(document);
    }
}


public class ReportMap : ClassMap<Report>
{
    public ReportMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.CreateDate);
        Map(x => x.LastModified);
        Map(x => x.AppointmentStart);
        Map(x => x.AppointmentEnd);
        Map(x => x.Type).CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.Status).CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.Kareo_Id);

        References<Patient>(x => x.Patient);
        HasMany<Document>(x => x.Documents)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: how many documents does he have befor and after? Can you look at the sql generated to see if there are really 2 inserts?

Comment: It is adding the same document twice on save.

Comment: are there any Eventlisteners on the session? Which Id generation do you use? As i understand the NH-code, it remembers which entities it has processed already and wouldn't process them again.

Comment: There is not eventlisteners on the session and Id generation is left to default ( native to sql)

Comment: I assume (perhaps wrongly) that User has a  HasMany<Document> in it's mapping. If that is not the case I am out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding AsSet to the mapping

```
    HasMany<Document>(x => x.Documents)
        .AsSet()
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All();
```

You would need to change IList to ICollection and initialize it with System.Collections.Generic.HashSet.

The cause of the problem is that you are probably adding the same document to the list twice and since it is not saved it gets inserted twice to the db.

Comment: But as you can see I am adding it once. So where is the duplication happening?

Comment: Maybe there is a circular reference in your object graph and an other parent of document also has Casecade.All().Inverse() this could also be the problem.

Comment: There is not other parent. Only report has documents. If you need me to post further code let me know.

Comment: From your sample above Document references User and Report

Comment: Issue was the duplication of SaveOrUpdate. This method helped me find the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping of an entity i take it as document map:
you should add

```
References<User>(x => x.User).Cascade.None();
```

Cascade.None() will stop cascading any changes.

Also you can use intellisense to give you options you can use when you write .Cascade.

Rev 2
this should be for both mappings

> References(x => x.User).Cascade.None(); References(x =>
>   x.Report).Cascade.None();

Comment: which element is duplicating? See my rev2

Comment: It is Document that gets duplicated not Report or User.

Comment: Only my thoughts are: are you using for saving the same session? try to change: References<Report>(x => x.Report); to HasOne(x=>x.Report) and maybe cascade none again